# MS Access Database in .NET Core

Tags: ms-access, asp.net-core, .net-core

I must read a MS Access in my ASP.NET Core application. The problem is, that OleDb is no longer supported in .NET Core. Is there another way to work with a MS Access database?

Comment: Hello did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ODBC. Install the System.Data.Odbc nuget.
For windows you might need to install the MS Access Database Engine Redistributable 2010 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
For *nix and Mac use MDBTools
You can see my blog post at https://mrojas.ghost.io/msaccess-in-dotnetcore/ for an step by step guide.